# Getting Access forbidden on new localhost project

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I'm attempting to setup a new webproject based off of the Open Source Point of sale system. I have followed the install steps as I usually do, but when I goto my *localhost/webproj* I get the following error:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is
>   either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.11

I have checked readonly flags on all files/folders, no problem there.

but there is this line in the readme which I'm having trouble verifying and wondering if that could be the cause.

> PHP needs to have `php-gd`, `php-bcmath`, `php-intl`, `php-sockets`
>   and `php-mcrypt` installed and enabled.

how do I check these php 'things' are installed and enabled?

EDIT: Using windows 10. logged in locally as an admin user. Single machine no domain.

Comment: have you checked ownership of the folder?

Comment: As @Option pointed out, Ownership of directories and files is the issue here

Comment: Checked, and I own all files, and no files have Readonly (or hidden/system) state.

Comment: Which apache tool you are using like xampp or wamp etc and where it is installed C:\ ?

Comment: xampp. have everything installed under a C:\DEV folder, but I have many running projects, just having this issue with this new install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it looks like this was caused by the new application having its index.html in a sub folder. If I launched directly from this sub folder it works. This was done to heighten security in the web application.

Answer (score 0):

CD into your localhost directory using terminal / cmd prompt and check for ownership permissions firstly.

`cd localhost` (my assumption, you may need to tweak this to where your localhost files are stored) then run `ls -ll` which will display your permissions and ownership information.

If you find the ownership is wrong run:

`chown -R yourUserName:staff webproj/*`

You can then run a chmod to be sure:

`chmod -R 755 webproj/*`

To run a test you could simply chmod the files to 777 to see if this allows entry.

Comment: Am using Win10, but I've done an ownership test (dir /q) as well as an attribute check (attrib). All looks in order.

Comment: the 777 thing doesn't relate to a windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is an index.php in that folder; or whatever is your default directory index? Default permissions are usually good, but there are times you may have to `chmod 777` on local dev to make things work. You can check modules with `phpinfo()`. Create a file, say phpinfo.php, and add just a single line like so: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Oh, and XAMPP is usually owned by root, at least on nix, so chowning htdocs to your own account will fail.

Comment: There is no index.php in the root of this installation. I did notice that when I dropped it in. but there is one under the application folder